# Access violation error C

Tags: c

I am a beginner and I am learning C and C++. I am trying to run this code in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Windows Desktop. This is a simple calculator code which I have written by myself! But whenever I run it I get this error `Unhandled exception at 0x519600B4 (msvcr110d.dll) in Calculator.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.`

Forgive me for any mistakes (it is my first time). Thank you!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

main ()
{
    int num1, num2, result;
    char oper;
    scanf_s("%d%c%d", &num1, &oper, &num2);
    switch(oper)
    {
    case '+':
        result = num1 + num2;
        printf("%d", result);
        break;
    case '-':
        result = num1 - num2;
        printf("%d", result);
        break;
    case '*':
        result = num1 * num2;
        printf("%d", result);
        break;
    case '/':
        result = num1 / num2;
        printf("%d", result);
        break;
    default:
        printf("ERROR: INVALID OR UNRECOGNISED INPUT\n");
        break;
    }
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: In general, you don't have to apologize for coding mistakes, they're not offensive since you're a beginner. :)

Comment: You could step through your code with the debugger and see when the error comes up.

Comment: This code should not compile on a standard C compiler for Windows. The correct format for main (for a hosted program such as this) is `int main (void)`. If you are a beginner, you should consider using a C standard-compliant compiler, or you will pick up lots of bad practice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When using [`scanf_s`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for the `%c` format string you must specify how many characters you wish to read:

```
scanf_s("%d%c%d", &num1, &oper, 1, &num2);
```

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) describes the requirement:

> Unlike scanf and wscanf, scanf_s and wscanf_s require the buffer size to be specified for all input parameters of type c, C, s, S, or string control sets that are enclosed in []. The buffer size in characters is passed as an additional parameter immediately following the pointer to the buffer or variable.

Comment: Thank you sir,then in this case it should it be like this?
"char oper[1];"

Comment: No, the declaration of the variable (`char oper;`) in your code is fine. You just need to add the character count parameter to the `scanf_s` call.

Comment: No. It is still a single char variable. You just need to specify the size in scanf_s. No sense in creating an array of length 1.

Comment: can you please tell me the syntax of the changes please

Comment: I did. You simply need to replace your line of code which calls `scanf_s` with the single line of code in my answer.

Comment: What I did not say in the answer, although I noticed it, is that your main declaration is non-standard. You should, for this program, use `int main(void)`.